# HTML5 autocomplete attribute is missing from apex:inputField

Tags: visualforce

HTML5 introduced a nice form input attribute called autocomplete. When you mark the input field with autocomplete="on" each value ever entered in the browser to that field will be automatically cached and displayed when you fill the form again. My question, why apex:inputField does not support that? it should reflect any attribute supported by HTML5 doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add attributes to many Visualforce components that are “passed through” to the rendered HTML. To add a pass-through attribute to, for example, an `<apex:inputText>` component, prefix the attribute with “html-” and set the attribute value as normal. This [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm) describes in detail.

```
<apex:inputText value="{!account.owner.name}" html-autocomplete="on"/>
```

As per Salesforce documentation, Pass-through attributes are supported by `<apex:inputField>`

Comment: It answers the question although the autocomplete is not working... I can see that the generated input field contains autocomplete="on" , very strange, do you know why?

Comment: As per w3schools,  In some browsers you may need to activate an autocomplete function for this to work (Look under "Preferences" in the browser's menu). Can you check your setting http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000604.htm.

Comment: It is turned on, in w3schools the autocomplete on is working fine in my Chrome browser, although in SalesForce site under SSL it simply fails to work... I am not sure why...